# "Request has unsupported document format" - AWS Textract, using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to make an algorithm in AWS Lambda using NodeJS 14.x with AWS SDK version 2.966.0 using AWS Textract (Analyze Expense).
Here is the code I have written:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk")
const textract = new AWS.Textract({apiVersion: '2018-06-27'});
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var params = {
    Document: {
      S3Object: {
        Bucket: '(REDACTED)',
        Name: 'test1.pdf'
      }
    }
  };
  try {
    const data = await textract.analyzeExpense(params).promise();
    return data;
  } catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
};
```

I am getting the error:

```json
{
  "message": "Request has unsupported document format",
  "code": "UnsupportedDocumentException",
  "time": "2021-08-11T22:07:59.913Z",
  "requestId": "f61104c6-fba6-4d97-8f5d-e4a4491a610b",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 62.83763773681126
}
```

I know that PDF is supported through an async API (whereas JPEGs and PNGs are with sync APIs) but isn't this already async? If not, how do I call it in async, allowing textract to accept the PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because PDF format is not supported by synchronous operations with Amazon Textract.

Currently, Analyze Expense is only supported by synchronous requests, link to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_AnalyzeExpense.html).

[image: synchronous requests]

If you need to process PDF files using `AnalyzeExpense`, one approach could be to split the PDF into multiple `.png` files.